# android how to replace fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, replace, fragment, fragmenttransaction

In my android project on focusing of a text view am replacing a fragment but i want to do same in on create how can i do that.
can i use input manager?

```
signUpPhoneNUmber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){   
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {if(hasFocus) {
//Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment           
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction. replace(R.id.RelativeLayout01,cardContactList);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
}
}
});
```

Comment: I'm confused on your question. You already have the fragment transaction code, just place it in your onCreate method.

Comment: ya i tried that but when i added that code onCreate am getting error,

Comment: null pointer exception, value of RelativeLayout01 will getting null value app is crashing,do u have any solution for that.

Comment: Please post your layout and activity code. The other thing is that you shouldn't be replacing the root level layout with your fragment. You should be replacing a child layout view with the fragment instead. Look up fragment swapping and see how it's done.